# Calling a method in Statelesswidget for splash screen?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building a Weather app for learning and at the beginning of app I want to get users location. Splash screen is stateless widget and don't do anything. When the locations is available I want to push to the another screen.

I am able to do it but is this a correct way to do(Please review below code)?.
Let me know any other solutions.

I call the `getLocation` method before returning the widget from build method. Is this the ideal way of doing? Because this screen state won't be updating.

```
class LaunchScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String id = 'launch_screen';

  void getLocation(BuildContext context) async {
    LocationData location = await LocationService().getCurrentLocation();
    if (location != null) {
      // Go to home
      print(location.latitude);
      print(location.longitude);
    } else {
      // Error fetching location
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getLocation(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(),
          ),
          Center(
            child: Image(
              image: AssetImage('images/launch_screen/app_logo.png'),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 8,
          ),
          Center(
            child: Shimmer.fromColors(
              baseColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.6),
              highlightColor: Colors.white,
              child: Text(
                'Forecasts',
                style: GoogleFonts.montserratAlternates(
                    textStyle:
                        TextStyle(fontSize: 60, fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
                    color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.6)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text(
                'Made with ❤️ ',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 12,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
                    color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5)),
              ),
              Text(
                'Parth Adroja',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 12,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5)),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `FutureBuilder` to do it.

like:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      initialData: null,
      future: getLocation(),
      builder: (context, snap){
        if(snap.hasData){
          return FullDataWidget(snap.data);
        }else{
          return SplashScreen();
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: FutureBuilder is nice thing to know.

Comment: What about when I receive the location I want to navigate to different screen instead of showing the FullDataWidget?

Comment: FullDataWidget it's a generic name that I used.
You can call any method before the 'return', include 'Navigator.push' , but when start to be complex the state managment it's better to use a StateFullWidget.

Comment: The reason I asked is because the builder needs a widget to be returned Right? Now before that I push it then there is no meaning to return any widget or in case I can return the SplashScreen though. But it don't make sense.

Comment: Yes I am now finding better to use stateful widget instead of stateless in this scenario

Comment: I think that is better to use a top Widget to manage when show Splash or FullDataWidget (or your Home). If you use the SplashScreen to go another page you will need to use Navigator.pushReplacement to exclude the Splash from Stack of the NAvigator, start to be very complex.